# Imperative Sieve of Eratosthenes using destructive updates in Haskell

Tags: performance, beginner, array, haskell, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've implemented the prime sieve of Eratosthenes in Haskell using a mutable array of unboxed Bools instead of the usual pure and immutable datastructures.

My main concern with this code is speed. For large upper bounds, it runs approximately 70% slower than C code implementing the same algorithm.
Memory is already optimal (1 bit per number plus some small overhead).

I would also like to know if the code is reasonably idiomatic, considering the fact that is impure, and basically non-functional (meaning imperative).
Any nitpicks are appreciated.

```
import Prelude
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray, (!))
import Data.Array.Storable (newArray, readArray, writeArray, getBounds)
import Data.Array.ST (STUArray, runSTUArray)
import Control.Monad (when)
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)

markMultiplesAsNotPrime :: STUArray s Int Bool -> Int -> ST s ()
markMultiplesAsNotPrime isPrime k = do
  (_, n) <- getBounds isPrime
  kIsPrime <- readArray isPrime k
  when kIsPrime $ do
    let multiples = takeWhile (<=n) $ iterate (+k) (k+k)
    mapM_ (\i -> writeArray isPrime i False) multiples

sieve :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
sieve n | n < 0 = undefined
sieve n = runSTUArray $ do
  isPrime <- newArray (2, n) True :: ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)
  let kMax = isqrt' n
  let ks = takeWhile (<=kMax) . iterate (+1) $ 2
  mapM_ (markMultiplesAsNotPrime isPrime) ks
  return isPrime

isqrt' :: Int -> Int
isqrt' = ceiling . (sqrt :: Double -> Double) . fromIntegral

primesSmallerThanOrEqualTo :: Int -> [Int]
primesSmallerThanOrEqualTo n | n < 2 = []
primesSmallerThanOrEqualTo n = let 
    isPrime = sieve n
  in
    [i | i <- [2 .. n], isPrime ! i]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  mapM_ (print . last . primesSmallerThanOrEqualTo . read) args
```

In case it is relevant:
I compiled and executed the code on an amd64 CPU using "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3" with the optimization switch "-O2".

Some timings (as measured with the runtime system switch "-s", best of five runs): $$ \begin{array}{4c} n & π(n) & t [s] & \log\left(\frac{t_2}{t_1}\right) \bigg/ \log\left(\frac{π(n_2)}{π(n_1)}\right) \\ 10^4 & 1.23 \cdot 10^3 & 2 \cdot 10^{-3} & - \\ 10^5 & 9.59 \cdot 10^3 & 4 \cdot 10^{-3} & 0.3 \\ 10^6 & 7.85 \cdot 10^4 & 1.0 \cdot 10^{-2} & 0.4 \\ 10^7 & 6.65 \cdot 10^5 & 9.3 \cdot 10^{-2} & 1.04 \\ 10^8 & 5.76 \cdot 10^6 & 1.25 \cdot 10^0 & 1.20 \\ 10^9 & 5.08 \cdot 10^7 & 1.43 \cdot 10^1 & 1.12 \\ 10^{10} & 4.55 \cdot 10^8 & 1.61 \cdot 10^2 & 1.10 \\ 10^{11} & 4.12 \cdot 10^9 & 1.88 \cdot 10^3 & 1.12 \end{array} $$

Comment: [*Empirical Orders of Growth, please!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) You can run the compiled executable with [`+RTS -s` switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%2BRTS+-s%22) to see some statistics report, including time. Anything below ~ n^1.05 is very good, below ~n^1.10 -- pretty decent (measuring it in `n` primes produced).

Comment: @WillNess I have added data on timing and empirical order of growth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`takeWhile (<=n) $ iterate (+k) (k+k)` can be written as `[2*k, 3*k..n]` which, here, can be replaced with `[k*k, k*k+k..n]`.

Similarly, `takeWhile (<= kMax) . iterate (+1) $ 2` can be written as `[2..kMax]`.

Algorithmically, we can work with odds only, and switch to `[k*k, k*k+2*k..n]` and `[3,5..kMax]` (special-casing the 2). Taking it further to pre-ignoring the multiples of *3* (*5,7*...) also, this is known as *wheel factorization* optimization.

`mapM` and `mapM_`, though very idiomatic, can be faster if coded manually as loops (recursive functions). This would also enumerate the numbers manually, instead of creating the interim lists and hoping the compiler won't actually  create them.

Using [`unsafeRead` and `unsafeWrite`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=unsafeRead+unsafeWrite) should be faster than the safe variants.

Lastly, `last . primesSmallerThanOrEqualTo` can be replaced with `lastPrime`,

```
lastPrime n = let arr = sieve n in
              take 1 [ i | i <- [n, n-1..2], arr ! i]
```

Even faster is to move the last prime-finding code into the `sieve` function itself, and return that prime from it, instead of the array.

Comment: Most of your suggestions improved performance a bit (I got it down to 80% of the original time). However, replacing the iteration with a list enumeration (`[2 .. kMax]`) led to a slowdown of more than 4. I'd also say that the time gained by replacing mapM_ with explicit recursion is not worth the ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of using `takeWhile`, you could simply compute largest divisible by `k` and smaller. That avoids needlessly checking condition for all indices.
2. Instead of using `undefined` it would be good to provide informative error message with `error`.
3. `STUArray` is strict in its elements already. So instead of taking `last` of primes, you can instead walk the array from the end (`[n..1]`) and use `dropWhile (not . (arr!!)` to get the last index that is `True`.
4. Aligning code blocks would make the code look nicer. (Like vertically aligning `=`.)

Comment: I don't understand your first suggestion. Could you elaborate on that?